# What does ECDF in the Python statsmodels api return?

Tags: python, statsmodels, ecdf

The `statsmodels` API says `Returns empirical CDF as a step function.`

That's a mathematical statement. In terms of Python variables and data structures what is the ECDF as a step function? Is it a tuple, list, array, scalar, etc.?

Comment: It's a numpy array as illustrated by the [docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html).

Comment: @jeremycg I was asking what the return of it was, not what ecdf was.

Comment: ok the function `ECDF` returns an 'ECDF' object, that works like a function, and returns a numpy array when called.